# Register app to open file type from any http(s) host

Tags: android, http, hyperlink, intentfilter

My app can open KML, KMZ & GPX files. My intent filter works well for the file & content schemes with file managers. It also used to work well for files hosted on web servers, but that's no longer the case: unless I add a data tag with a host attribute set to the server's domain to my intent filter, Chrome only proposes me to download the file (of course I can't do that, since I what the user to be able to open these files with my app from any website).

Did they break that as well, or is there still a way to make it work?